# Obfuscate Portable Class Library in SmartAssembly

Tags: obfuscation, portable-class-library, smartassembly

I have created portable class library with following configuration:
[image]

After this I have added my library into SmartAssebly 6.8, and try to build, but following error occured:
[image]

How to avoid this? I see that SA found right mscorelib.dll, but why it need System.Console?

Comment: Does *SmartAssembly* even work with PCL assemblies? According to the [FAQ](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/faq), Windows Store apps are *not* supported.

Comment: I have unchecked .Net for Windows Store, and check the checkbox Windows Phone 7, but still get the same error. Now mscorelib from Profile2 was found.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely an issue with SmartAssembly. I'd contact their customer service.

Depending on the selected platforms, Portable Class Libraries expose different assemblies. In many cases, tools like SmartAssembly that inspect or rewrite the assemblies make hard coded assumptions about the assembly identities types are declared in. In the past, that often worked because those assumptions matched the reality by happenstance.

The correct way would be to resolve types against the same set of assemblies the IDE/the compilers are referencing.